# Binary value of a line of code in mips

Tags: mips

Hello everyone I am having trouble figuring this out, the question wants me to give the value of the line of code in a binary value of the offset field not too sure what to do please help.

```
add $t0, $zero, $zero

addi $a0, $zero, 21

loop: 

beq $a0, $zero, end

add $t0, $t0, $a0

addi $a0, $a0, -3

j loop

end
```

For `beq $a0, $zero, end` give the binary value of the offset field. Briefly explain.

Comment: i know what the code is doing but what im confused on is what its asking for, what does it mean when it asks for the value of the offset field

Comment: We were not in the class we dont have the text book we dont necessarily know the terminology the professor is using here.

Comment: if the answer is 3 does that help? The answer keys just says 3 im not sure how she got 3, any ideas as to how?

Comment: well walk through the program by hand until something related to that instruction is a 3 and see if that makes sense.  what did you get when you with pencil and paper and/or single stepped through a simulator/debugger found for every instances of that instruciton?

Comment: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/jump.html

Comment: thank you markgz i think i figured it out, the offset field for beq is "end" and it has the value 3 bc its the third label used. not sure if thats right but thats the only way i get the number 3